# Where does $HOME variable comes from and why I can't change it?

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

I know this is stupid, but last 30 minutes I am trying to change $HOME variable to other value, doing `$Env:HOME = "desired value"` did nothing for me, I tried couple other suggestions from the first 10 results from Google and not I am actually stuck, hence asking this rather stupid question.

Here is why I want to change it. I gave my laptop to our IT's because my hard disk broke and I had to replace it with new one, so I wanted them to install me fresh Windows image which they did, but then they put for a user name that is stupid and I want to replace.

I searched in internet and saw that changing actually the name of user is not an easy job, so I've decided to create new and move slowly to it. What do I mean move slowly to him? - all my apps currently are working with the previous user (C:\Users\annoyingUser) installing\storing everything there which I would like to change.

Then I noticed that `$HOME` is referring to C:\Users\annoyingUser and I presume a lot of applications use this variable so I've decided to change it value, but with no success so far.

tl;dr; Can you guys help me change its value, seems like I am missing something?

Things I've tried so far in powershell:

1. `$Env:HOME = "C:\Users\DesiredUser"`
2. Noticed that I don't have such variable(hence asking where $HOME comes from since when I use it in the terminal everything looks fine)  in environment variables window so I've added one for the user and one system. - didn't work either way.
3. `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HOME","C:\Users\DesiredUser")`

Comment: Hint: Searching for [powershell environment variable HOME](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-ab&ei=oo0lW-yUGsHwgQaWm5ugBg&q=powershell+environment+variable+HOME&oq=powershell+environment+variable+HOME&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l3.119981.122050.0.123161.6.6.0.0.0.0.783.1376.0j4j6-1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.5.1374...0.0.r0JfB6rsERQ) would have given you the answer immediately.

Comment: Well I wasnt expecting to be anything special so I  decided to search for something more generic. Oh well.. thank you anyway.